# How to add biography of user while importing?

Tags: import

We are importing user details from Lithium to Wordpress using java app which generates XML file.
I need to know key for Biography so that we can include that in XML file.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, user's Biography is saved in User Meta table with `description` key.